# Python: How do i sort data in a text file?

Tags: python

i am trying to write inside a .txt file and then sort in alphabetical order the names inside, then print. How would i do this? If it can't be done is there any alternative?

```
print("Well done " + name + "! your total score is: {}/10 :)\n".format(score))
#os.system("color 0a")
time.sleep(3)
file = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "a") # Creates a file.txt if it hasn't already been created and ammends it 'a'
file.write(name + " " + str(age) + " {}\n".format(score)) # Writes into the file, .format(x) replaces {} with the variable x
file.close
f = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
lines.sort()
f = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "w")
for line in lines:
    f.write(line)
print(lines)
f.flush()
f.close()
```

Comment: Why are you sleeping? Use ``list.sort()`` or ``sorted(iterable)``

Comment: please tell us what the file looks like?

Comment: Could you show me in code form, cause this is for lists i think

Comment: @JamesMills Where is the list? or Iterable

Comment: The file is text file(.txt) when it writes in the file it starts a new line, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

i am guessing the input looks like -

```
a 10 1
b 10 2
c 10 8
d 10 5
```

Making sure that each name is on a separate line, which does not seem to be the case with your code, since file.write() does not automatically append a `\n` to the end, you have to manually do it -

```
file.write(name + " " + str(age) + " {}\n".format(score))
```

Then you can do -

```
f = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
lines.sort()
f = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "w")
for line in lines:
    f.write(line)
f.flush()
f.close()
```

Comment: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='3.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
>>>

Comment: I got that when i put: print(f)

Comment: yes, correct, maybe you want to do `print(lines)` in above code, or if you only have f , then `print(f.readlines())` .
Do not print the file object itself , that would not give you any meaningful information.

Comment: Where are you doing this? What line ? Can you show the complete code you are using?
Regarding the IOUnsupportedError , you must have tried doing f.readlines() after you openned f with mode as "w" , you cannot do that.

Comment: Like I said, issue with your program, you are assuming file.write() with add' '\n' after each line, which is not the case, you have to manually do that.
Also, fix the file, to make sure each name/age/score combination is in a new line. and then try the code.

Comment: It only prints the first letter of the name when i put print(lines)

Comment: the age variable is a class number i.e.: 1, 2 and 3 only.

Comment: Can you check the file to see if each name is in a separate line?
Also, check the file if the file really does consist of complete names, or the file itself only consists of the first letter

Comment: When a new user is inputted into the text file it only reads: ['\n', 'MICHAEL 1 0'] even though i dont see the /n anywhere.

Comment: the \n may be an extra line in the file, a newline is interpreted as \n

Answer (score 0):

```
import random, time, operator, os # Import modules required for specific tasks

def quiz():
    score = 0
    for q in range (1,11): # 'for' loop: Repeats the lines between 0 to 11 times- 10 times
        ops = {'+':operator.add,
               '-':operator.sub,
               '*':operator.mul}
        op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
        if op != '*': # != means 'not equal'
            r1 = random.randint (-1, 100) # Randomises a number from -1 to 100
            r2 = random.randint (-1, 100)
            answer = ops.get(op)(r1,r2)
        else:
            r1 = random.randint(-1,12)
            r2 = random.randint(-1,12)
            answer = ops.get(op)(r1,r2)
        if equ == answer :
            score += 1 
            print("Correct, Well done, your score is: " + str(score))
        elif end - start >= 20:
            print("You took too long to answer.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect, Sorry. Your score is: " + str(score))

    print("Well done " + name + "! your total score is: {}/10 :)\n".format(score))
    time.sleep(3)
    file = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "a") # Creates a file.txt if it hasn't already been created and ammends it 'a'
    file.write(name + " " + str(age) + " {}".format(score)) # Writes into the file, .format(x) replaces {} with the variable x
    file.close
    f = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    lines.sort()
    f = open(str(age) + ".txt" , "w")
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
    print(lines)
    f.flush()
    f.close()

start = "" # Defines a variable
while start not in ('Y', 'y', 'yes', 'Yes') : # Repeats the lines beneath until the condition is met i.e.: input = 'y'
    name = input("Welcome to the Maths Quiz! Please enter your name: \n").upper()
    age = input("Enter your class number: 1, 2 or 3 \n")
    while age not in ('1', '2', '3') :
        age = input("Enter your class number: 1, 2 or 3 \n")
    start = input("You are " + name + " in class: " + str(age) + "\nIs this right? Enter y=Yes or n=No \n" )
time.sleep(2)
print("Get ready! The Quiz will now begin!") # Displays on the screen
time.sleep(2)
quiz() # Runs the function quiz
```

Comment: What is the issue you are seeing now?